# Why does this Firebase Database security rule with && and || not work

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

In an iOS app I am creating using Firebase, each user has an unique username which is created after they sign up with an email and password.

So if a user with an email of test5@gmail.com had signed up and then had to create a unique username which isn't in the username database a snippet of the database would be as follows:

```
    "usernames" : {
        "test" : "r6KPesUr1qORfIJke07SloZHeNW2",
        "test1" : "jSMSkY9rHtdNkXoLrsFmCAXdY9n2",
        "test7" : "jnFhJbgCjZeJFx0hspObqoskQej2",
        "test8" : "HtnULzU0lnZKYva2M2Wepl6N8wE3"
    },

    "users" : {
        "HtnULzU0lnZKYva2M2Wepl6N8wE3" : {
            "email" : "test8@gmail.com",
            "username" : "test8"
        },
        "boX6rtJ98haWVxNoXfSq21maCVU2" : {
            "email" : "test5@gmail.com"
        },
        "jSMSkY9rHtdNkXoLrsFmCAXdY9n2" : {
            "email" : "Test1@gmail.com",
            "username" : "test1"
        },
        "jnFhJbgCjZeJFx0hspObqoskQej2" : {
            "email" : "test7@gmail.com",
            "username" : "test7"
        },
        "r6KPesUr1qORfIJke07SloZHeNW2" : {
            "email" : "test6@gmail.com",
            "username" : "test"
        }
    }
```

I have the following security rules in place to ensure a username is unique when a user completes signing up.

```
    // USERNAMES
    "usernames": {
        ".read": "auth.uid != null",
        ".write": "auth.uid != null",
        "$username": {
            ".validate": "(!root.child('usernames').hasChild($username.toLowerCase()) && newData.val() == auth.uid && 
                          root.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid)) &&

                          (root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/username').val().toLowerCase() == $username || 
                          !root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/username').exists())"                 
        }                                   
    }
```

For the validation rules I would like to have these three statements as must haves

```
   (!root.child('usernames').hasChild($username.toLowerCase()) && 
     newData.val() == auth.uid && 
     root.child('users').hasChild(auth.uid))
```

and with these two statement one of them has to be true

```
   "(root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/username').val().toLowerCase() == $username || 
    (!root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/username').exists()"
```

so if the user wanted to sign up with **test5** as there username with the following json then it wouldn't work with my current security rules due to the first part of the OR statement.

```
     "users": {
         "boX6rtJ98haWVxNoXfSq21maCVU2": {
              "username": "test5"
          }
     }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's quite hard to parse the rules. Can you edit your question to include the minimal code that would get rejected by this validation rule, but that you want to allow?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sure thing. I have added how the database would look and the json that would subsequently fail to be written to create a unique username for the user with an email of test5@gmail.com

Comment: OK. I tried figuring out your use-case. But it's tricky to understand from such complex rules, so I isolated one (well two) specific use-case and focused on that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen you absolutely nailed it again. that was my exact use case. not sure what else to say but thanks a lot. Firebase is awesome

Comment: Good to hear that I guessed right Edward. There are a lot of security rules questions recently, so my head hurts more and more. :-) Have fun hacking on Firebase!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you want two things to happen for a user to claim a user name:

1. a node is written under `/users/$uid/username` with their user name
2. a node is written under `/usernames/$username` with their UID

Your JSON snippet that you write now only contains #1. It contains nothing about writing the user name under `/usernames`. So the rule will reject it, because you're validating that the username must exist and be claimed for that user.

You probably want to validate that #1 and #2 happen at the same time, which would be a multi-location update like:

```
 "users/boX6rtJ98haWVxNoXfSq21maCVU2/username": "test5",
 "usernames/test5": "boX6rtJ98haWVxNoXfSq21maCVU2"
```

Your rules would be:

```
"usernames": {
  "$username": {
    ".validate": "!data.exists() && 
      newData.exists() &&
      newData.parent().parent().child('users').child(auth.uid).child('username').val() === $username"
    }                                   
}
"users": {
  "$uid": {
    "username": {
      ".validate": "!data.exists() && 
        newData.exists() &&
        newData.parent().parent().parent().child('usernames').child(newData.val()).val() === $uid"
    }
  }
}
```

I removed the bit about lowercase, because it's easier to fix that in your code and only store lowercase user names.

Comment: I think you need to remove the brackets from newData() for the end rules in both "users" and "usernames"

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean there. Feel free to suggest an edit though.